# UseState ReactNative

Tags: react-native

1

Begginer developer react native.

im dealing with design pattern issue , i have multiple TouchableOpacity's in the same component (i have to keep it that way). for each one i have onPress function thats changs there background and reverse . the problom is that the function dependent on State current statment and when i click on one of them evreyone is changing .

```
   function Grocery({ navigation }) {
    
      const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(0);
      const onPress = () => setIsPressed(!isPressed);
    
    
    
      return (  
        
        <ScrollView>
          <Button title="home" onPress={() => {FindMatch(GetIngridients());navigation.navigate("MatchedRecipiesScreen");}}>press</Button>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => {AddToPanetry("pasta");onPress();}}  >
        <View style={isPressed && styles.pressedButtonStyle} />
            <Image style={styles.imageright} source={require('../assets/Pastaa.jpg')} />
            <Text> pasta</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    
    
    
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {AddToPanetry("eggs");onPress();}}  >
          <View style={isPressed && styles.pressedButtonStyle} />
            <Image style={styles.imageleft} source={require('../assets/eggs.jpg')} />
            <Text>eggs</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>


<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {AddToPanetry("sugar");onPress();}}  >
          <View style={isPressed && styles.pressedButtonStyle} />
            <Image style={styles.imageleft} source={require('../assets/sugar.jpg')} />
            <Text>eggs</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    
    
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          container: {
            flexDirection: "row",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            padding: 50,
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
          }
          ,
          imageleft: {
            borderRadius:100,
            borderWidth:2,
            borderColor:'black',
            height: 120,
            width: 150,
            borderRadius: 80,
            padding:25
          },
          button: {
            alignItems: "center",
           
          },
            tinyLogo: {
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
          },
          pressedButtonStyle: {
            position:"absolute",
            width:150,
            height:121,
            backgroundColor:'black',
            opacity:0.6,
            zIndex:100,
            borderRadius:80
          },
          imageright: {
            borderRadius:100,
            borderWidth:2,
            borderColor:'black',
            height: 120,
            width: 150,
            borderRadius: 80,
            padding:25
          }
        });
```

Can someone plz show me the right way to use UseState with boolean array in this case ?

tnx.

Comment: If you need three stateful buttons, use three state fields. Or better yet, create a new component called ToggleButton that encapsulates that state for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the render prop pattern to encapsulate only the logic that is giving you trouble.

```
const ToggleWrapper = ({render, onPress}) => {
      const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(0);
      const _onPress = () => setIsPressed(!isPressed);

  return <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {_onPress();onPress();}}  >
          {render(isPressed)}
          </TouchableOpacity>
}
```